# Creating a NextJS app using firebase - firebase works on local but fails on vercel production

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

I am using firebase in NextJs local and all is working fine

.env.local

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY="xxxxxxx"
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN="yyyyyyy"
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL="zzzzzzzz"
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID="xxxxxxx"
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET="yyyyyyyy"
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID="zzzzzzzz"
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID="xxxxxxxx"
```

clientApp.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";

const clientCredentials = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(clientCredentials);
}

export default firebase;
```

However, when I deploy via Vercel, I get these console errors:

```
@firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL. Be sure to include  a Project ID when calling firebase.initializeApp(). 

Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL. Be sure to include  a Project ID when calling firebase.initializeApp().
```

Has anyone come up against a similar error before?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put env variables on verce panel https://vercel.com/USER-NAME/PROJECT-ID/settings/environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all the hassles, just create a `.env` file in the project's directory and add all the credentials. also in the file `.firebaserc` file check whether the contents holds like this,

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "your firebase project ID",
    "webapp": "your firebase project ID"
  }
}
```

If you have any more trouble, look into this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14420#discussioncomment-29816